# How to terminate variable expansion to create a string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I tell powershell the end of a variable to be expanded into a string when it sits next to other alphabetic characters?

$StringToAdd = "iss"
$CompeteString = "Miss$StringToAddippi"

Thanks!

Comment: I like the incomplete name of variable `$CompeteString` :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use curly braces, `{` and `}`, to delimit the variable expansion.  For example:

```
PS C:\> $StringToAdd = "iss"
PS C:\> $CompeteString = "Miss${StringToAdd}ippi"
PS C:\> $CompeteString
Mississippi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use $()

```
PS C:\> $StringToAdd = "iss"
PS C:\> $CompeteString = "Miss$($StringToAdd)ippi"
PS C:\> $CompeteString
Mississippi
```

The sub-expression operator for double-quoted strings is described [here](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens). Whatever is in the brackets should be evaluated first. This can be a variable or even an expression.

```
PS C:\> $CompeteString = "Miss$($StringToAdd.length * 2)ippi"
PS C:\> $CompeteString
Miss6ippi
```

Answer (score 0):

$CompleteString="Miss"+$StringToAdd+"ippi"