# Powershell pass string to ForEach

Tags: variables, powershell, csv, dynamic, foreach

I am trying to import a csv file and spitting out the columns in a pipe delimited format.

```
Import-csv file.dat | foreach {($_.'Column1')+ "|" +($_.'Column2')+ "|" +($_.'Column3')}
```

This works great when I am explicitly passing the column values

```
($_.'ColumnX' + "|" $_.'ColumnY') etc.
```

I want to pass a string of variables generated dynamically to the foreach component.

I am able to generate a "string" which looks exactly as

```
"($_.'Column1')+ "|" +($_.'Column2')+ "|" +($_.'Column3')"
```

however, powershell is treating that generated string as a single column and outputs the first column ONLY.

eg.

```
$columns = ($_.'Column1')+ "|" +($_.'Column2')+ "|" +($_.'Column3')
Import-csv file.dat | foreach {$columns}
```

Any advise on how to get the column string passed under the foreach section so that I get the correct output?

Comment: Are you just trying to convert the commas to pipes? Why not use `-replace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Import-csv file.dat | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is great. It definitely works! 

But, I have spent more than 2 days trying to figure out how to get the dynamic variables added to the foreach group. I would like to know how can I pass strings as dynamic variables!

Comment: Do you mean you  are wanting to pass an array of the property names (column headings)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to read a CSV (comma separated value) file and output it as a vertical bar "|" separated file. If this is the case, you can do the following:

```
gc file.dat | % {[string]::join("|", $_.split(','))}
```

This just reads the line, splits it into fields at each comma and joins them with vertical bars.

Following your comment on @mjolnir's answer, here is how to use dynamic field names within the foreach block:

```
$f1 = "ColumnA"
$f2 = "ColumnB"
import-csv file.dat | % {$_.$($f1) + "|" + $_.$($f1)}
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731345/how-to-terminate-variable-expansion-to-create-a-string-in-powershell/20305994#20305994) for explanation.

Comment: Yes, thats the plan and @mjolinor's solution works fine too. But, I would love to understand how to pass string as a dynamic parameter to foreach or anything else. Thanks

Comment: `$()` tells PS to first evaluate the expression inside the parentheses. So the foreach block becomes `{$_.ColumnA + "|" + $_.ColumnB}`